# Shouldn't the Private Beta link be removed?

Tags: bug

On [Help-Asking](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/asking), at the bottom there is a [How to Ask Questions in Private Beta](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask-beta) link:

> [image: Screenshot of Help-Asking page]

Shouldn't this be removed now, as SFF.SE is no longer in beta?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290401/299342

Comment: Ah! Ok. I see :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That page in the help centre isn't editable even by mods. Removing the irrelevant link would require an SE employee.

Also, the "How to Ask in Private Beta" link seems to be on every SE site, [even Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). So removing it would be a system-wide change which should be requested on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). **Edit:** it [already was requested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290401/278659) two years ago, with so far zero response from SE employees. So there's not much point in posting a duplicate there either. (Thanks @Null for the link!)

**Yes, it should be removed, but discussing it here won't achieve anything.**

Comment: Even posted here on this meta [the bug report will still get noticed](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1606/1204). And it won't necessarily do more being posted on Meta.SE than being posted here. So, I would not agree that discussing it here will not achieve anything.